# I'm struggling with this binomial expansion question. What should I do?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

Here's the question. I've done A, but I'm stuck on B and C. Can someone please show me how it is done?

Answer (score 0):

The starting four binomial coefficients for the $8$-th power are $1$, $8$, $28$ and $56$.

Thus the expansion of $(1+3x)^8$ is
$$
(1+3x)^8=1+8\cdot 3x+28\cdot 9x^2+56\cdot 27x^3+x^4P(x)
$$
for some polynomial $P(x)$. Similarly,
$$
(1-3x)^8=1-8\cdot 3x+28\cdot 9x^2-56\cdot 27x^3+x^4P(-x)
$$
by just replacing $x$ with $-x$. Then the sum is...

Next note that $1.000003^8=(1+3\cdot0.000001)^8$ and $0.999997^8=(1-3\cdot0.000001)^8$.

Comment: I go a different answer for the starting binomial coefficients...How did you get 1,8, 28, and 56?

Comment: @KrishaanKhubchand I computed them with the usual rule for the Tartaglia/Pascal triangle; after your comment I checked on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Pascal.27s_triangle) and, lo and behold, they're right. `;-)`